# How to code for knob control in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have found this Activex control (Knob Control 2.0) in the controls library but I don't know how to utilize this one as I have been unable to link its value to any cell. Can I get some help to links its values to any cell.

Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Comment: Unless its specifically designed for excel you will likely have to code some VBA to update a cell value when an event is fired by the control.

Comment: If you can find the name of the file the control is part of we might be able to help more. I can't find it anywhere on my system.